# Get inner values of a dynamically created LI element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a search suggestion list. For that, I have created the list dynamically using append function. For search purposes, I have set the `data-search-term` attribute and the `innerHTML` value of the `li` elements to be the same. Now what I need is when a user clicks on any `li` element the search field should get the `innerHTML` value. Simply what google search is. I have tried using event delegation to get the clicked element, but it's not working. Following is the function is just for checking whether event delegation is working but I do not get a pop up on my web page.

```
$("#suggestions").on("click", "a", function() {
    confirm("clicked");
});
```

The search suggestion list has an id *suggestions*.

[image]

This is my search field where the selected element's value needs to go.

```
<input class="form-control" name="query" type="text" placeholder="Offer" />
```

Also here is the code for creating the list.

```
var searchitems = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8"];

var len = searchitems.length;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    $('#suggestions').append('<li class="suggestItem">' + '<a>' + searchitems[i] + '</a>' + '</li>');
}
```

Comment: Where is the search box html?

Comment: Post the complete code to work with.. The image and all are not much helpful.

Comment: Do you want autocomplete search box like google with your databse?

Comment: yes Vikas. Similar to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen for `click` events on `.suggestItem` elements, not the whole list represented by `#suggestions` . Take a look at the example below.

```js
$(".suggestItem").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#selected-item').val($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="suggestions">
  <li class="suggestItem"><a href="">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="suggestItem"><a href="">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="suggestItem"><a href="">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="suggestItem"><a href="">Item 4</a>
  </li>
  <li class="suggestItem"><a href="">Item 5</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<input id="selected-item" type="text" placeholder="selected value will appear here" />
```

Comment: Tried this but not working. Just FYI(if necessary) the list in my code is dynamically generated. here it is.
<script>

 var searchitems = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8"];

 var len = searchitems.length;

 var i;

 for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

     $('#suggestions').append('<li class="suggestItem">' + '<a>' + searchitems[i] + '</a>' + '</li>');

 }
</script>

Comment: @kiranghule27 how are you clicking `li` if you have set `display:none;` to it.

Comment: @kiranghule27 if you insert your JS code which generates the list items into my snippet, it still works. I assume that the `display: none` is your issue ( as @krsoni already mentioned )

Comment: @RamisWachtler okay. I'll look into it.

Comment: @RamisWachtler I tried running my snippet in JS fiddle also. There it works. I don't understand where the problem is. 

http://jsfiddle.net/kiranghule27/7Lh5k3bw/2/#&togetherjs=F6gBcp1iV7